# removing gibberish from sentences

Tags: r, text-mining

During text cleaning, is it possible to detect and remove junk like this from sentences:

```
x <- c("Thisisaverylongexample and I was to removeitnow", "thisisjustjunk but I do I remove it")
```

currently I'm doing something like this:

```
str_detect(x, pattern = 'Thisisaverylongexample'))
```

but the more I review my dataframe, I found more sentences with this type of junk. How do I use something like regex to detect and remove rows with something junk like this?

Comment: Do you want `str_remove(x, 'Thisisaverylongexample')` Or `gsub('Thisisaverylongexample', '', x)`?

Comment: I want a something like this:  gsub('Thisisaverylongexample', '', x).  Bascially, how to detect junk like this  in a sentence.

Comment: For that you need to define "junk" first. Even with regex you need to define some rules to detect such junk. It looks junk to a naked eye but how do you tell a computer that?

Comment: Is one defining feature of what you call 'junk' that it's an unusually long string? If so, you can define a rule accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'junk' is detectable via its unusual length, you can define a rule accordingly. For example, if you want to get rid of words of 10 or more characters, this would extract them:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\b\\w{10,}\\b")
[[1]]
[1] "Thisisaverylongexample" "removeitnow"           

[[2]]
[1] "thisisjustjunk"
```

and this would get rid of them:

```
trimws(gsub("\\b\\w{10,}\\b", "", x))
[1] "and I was to"         "but I do I remove it"
```

Data:

```
x <- c("Thisisaverylongexample and I was to removeitnow", "thisisjustjunk but I do I remove it")
```